# Фразеологизм "ни-ни"

Tags: фразеология, егэ

Является ли междометие *ни-ни* фразеологизмом?
Под определение вроде подходит: это устойчивое сочетание слов, равное по значению целому предложению (делать отказ). К тому же есть подобные фразеологизмы из одного слова, как один-одинёшенек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Междометие *ни-ни* фразеологизмом не является.

[**ФРАЗЕОЛОГИЗМ** *Лингв.* Устойчивое словосочетание, оборот речи, выражение, значение которого не складывается из значений составляющих его слов; идиома.](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC&all=x)

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]